# Cassandra consistency ONE updating all replicas

Tags: cassandra

I am updating a record in Cassandra where I have set the consistency as ONE in my cqlsh session. I have enabled tracing for analyzing write performance.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE jesi WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

```
cqlsh:jesi> update reference_id set number_sequence = '0000503' where id = '54';
```

```
Tracing session: a099c320-40d4-11ee-943a-ab6b7cb26b14

 activity                                                                                                   | timestamp                  | source     | source_elapsed | client
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------+-----------
                                                                                         Execute CQL3 query | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.675000 | 172.17.0.3 |              0 | 127.0.0.1
 Parsing update reference_id set number_sequence = '0000503' where id = '54'; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.677000 | 172.17.0.3 |           2921 | 127.0.0.1
                                                          Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.681000 | 172.17.0.3 |           6190 | 127.0.0.1
                                            Determining replicas for mutation [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.686000 | 172.17.0.3 |          11466 | 127.0.0.1
           Sending MUTATION_REQ message to /172.17.0.2:7000 message size 94 bytes [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.688000 | 172.17.0.3 |          12989 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                   Appending to commitlog [MutationStage-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.689000 | 172.17.0.3 |          14357 | 127.0.0.1
                                                          Adding to reference_id memtable [MutationStage-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.689001 | 172.17.0.3 |          14557 | 127.0.0.1
           Sending MUTATION_REQ message to /172.17.0.4:7000 message size 94 bytes [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.690000 | 172.17.0.3 |          14955 | 127.0.0.1
                              MUTATION_REQ message received from /172.17.0.3:7000 [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.696000 | 172.17.0.4 |           1133 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                   Appending to commitlog [MutationStage-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.700000 | 172.17.0.4 |           5546 | 127.0.0.1
                                                          Adding to reference_id memtable [MutationStage-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.700001 | 172.17.0.4 |           5872 | 127.0.0.1
                                                   Enqueuing response to /172.17.0.3:7000 [MutationStage-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.705000 | 172.17.0.4 |          10539 | 127.0.0.1
                              MUTATION_REQ message received from /172.17.0.3:7000 [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.708000 | 172.17.0.2 |           1072 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                   Appending to commitlog [MutationStage-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.721000 | 172.17.0.2 |          23532 | 127.0.0.1
           Sending MUTATION_RSP message to /172.17.0.3:7000 message size 34 bytes [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.722000 | 172.17.0.4 |          27269 | 127.0.0.1
                              MUTATION_RSP message received from /172.17.0.4:7000 [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.723000 | 172.17.0.3 |             78 | 127.0.0.1
                                                          Adding to reference_id memtable [MutationStage-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.727000 | 172.17.0.2 |          29943 | 127.0.0.1
                                                   Enqueuing response to /172.17.0.3:7000 [MutationStage-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.728000 | 172.17.0.2 |          31492 | 127.0.0.1
                                         Processing response from /172.17.0.4:7000 [RequestResponseStage-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.729000 | 172.17.0.3 |           5809 | 127.0.0.1
           Sending MUTATION_RSP message to /172.17.0.3:7000 message size 34 bytes [Messaging-EventLoop-3-1] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.738000 | 172.17.0.2 |          40877 | 127.0.0.1
                              MUTATION_RSP message received from /172.17.0.2:7000 [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.739000 | 172.17.0.3 |             29 | 127.0.0.1
                                         Processing response from /172.17.0.2:7000 [RequestResponseStage-3] | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.740000 | 172.17.0.3 |            402 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           Request complete | 2023-08-22 10:14:06.711784 | 172.17.0.3 |          36784 | 127.0.0.1
```

```
cqlsh:jesi> consistency
Current consistency level is ONE.
```

Even though the consistency is set to `ONE`. In the tracing logs, we are seeing data is getting updated to all three replicas (i.e. 3 occurrences of `Appending to commit log` and `Adding to reference_id memtable`).
With consistency ONE isn't only one replica was supposed to receive the update for the session `a099c320-40d4-11ee-943a-ab6b7cb26b14` and all other replicas shall get the update in the background but not as part of the same session id?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is by design that a request will be sent to **all replicas** irrespective of the consistency level (CL) being issued in the request.

In Apache Cassandra, the consistency level determines how many replicas must acknowledge a read or write operation before it is considered successful.

The consistency level doesn't directly relate to session IDs. Session IDs are typically used to identify a client's session with the server, whereas the consistency level is a configuration

In your case, the `jesi` keyspace tables will always have `3` replicas per the definition for the holding the data.

When using a consistency level of `ONE` in Apache Cassandra, it means that only one replica needs to acknowledge a write operation for it to be considered successful. However, this doesn't mean that only one replica will receive the data.

Here's how it works:

1. **Write Request**: When a write request is made with a consistency level of `ONE`, the coordinator node (which receives the client's request) sends the write request to all replicas responsible for the data.
2. **Acknowledgment**: Only one replica needs to acknowledge the write for the operation to be considered successful from the client's perspective. The coordinator will respond to the client as soon as one replica acknowledges the write.
3. **Replication**: Even though only one acknowledgment is required, the write is still sent to all replicas responsible for that piece of data. Other replicas will eventually receive and apply the write, ensuring that the data is consistent across all replicas.
4. **Hinted Handoff**: If any replicas are down or fail to respond, the coordinator may store a "hint" that allows it to replay the write to those replicas when they become available again. This helps ensure eventual consistency.

The session ID doesn't play a direct role in this process. It might be used to identify the client's session with the coordinator, but it doesn't affect how the data is replicated to the replicas.

In summary, even with a consistency level of `ONE`, all replicas responsible for the data will eventually receive the write. The consistency level simply controls how many replicas must acknowledge the write for it to be considered successful from the client's perspective. The underlying replication mechanism ensures that all replicas receive the data, providing eventual consistency.

*TIP*: It is better to use `LOCAL_ONE | LOCAL_QUORUM` as the CL value so your request doesn't need to cross datacenters when you add more DCs to your cluster in future. Saves time with app change.

Comment: I am in a situation where some of the updates even though the query shows were successful it's not updating the table when a read operation is performed. 
In that case, will LOCAL_QUORUM help? as updates are not reflecting even after 1 hour of wait time

Comment: You either have a cluster that is not properly sized for the load that you're using or there is some other problem that `system.log` and/or `debug.log` will help you find. `LOCAL_QUORUM` is always the preferred consistency level for most use cases for both writes & reads.

Comment: Also, if this was your original problem, you should have stated it correctly as opposed to asking a different question. This would have helped sped up the triage here.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described and observed is working as advertised.

The consistency level for write requests determines the number of replicas that must respond to the coordinator with an acknowledgement that the write was successful. The crucial thing to know is that mutations (writes) are sent by the coordinator to ALL replicas in ALL data centres, regardless of the number of replicas or DCs.

For example, let's assume we have a cluster with 2 DCs each with 5 nodes. For a keyspace with a replication factor of 3 for all DCs, there is a total of 6 replicas (2 DCs x 3 replicas/DC).

A write request with a consistency level of `ONE` will only wait for a response from one node (the fastest node) for the write to be considered successful. A write request with a CL of `LOCAL_QUORUM`, two replicas in the local DC must acknowledge the write.

In contrast, the consistency level for read requests determines the number of replicas that will be requested for the data. For a read request with a CL of `LOCAL_ONE`, only one node in the local DC will be queried by the coordinator. For a CL of `LOCAL_QUORUM`, two replicas (quorum of RF=3 is 2) will be queried by the coordinator -- one with the actual data, another with just a digest request.

Contrary to your understanding, replication to ALL replicas takes place in real-time -- NOT in the background.

If you're interested, the [Dynamo Architecture](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/trunk/cassandra/architecture/dynamo.html) page on the Apache Cassandra website explains it in a bit more detail. Cheers!